# ActiveRecord::Relation trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and *I would like to "subtract" two `ActiveRecord::Relation` "entities" and have back again an `ActiveRecord::Relation`*. That is, I have two `ActiveRecord::Relation` objects (`@articles` and `@articles_checked`) and the following code:

```
@unchecked_articles = @articles - @articles_checked

# $  @unchecked_articles.class
# => Array

@unchecked_articles.method_call
# raise a NoMethodError error (read above for more information).
```

The above code, anyway, returns a Ruby `Array` so I can not "play" (use `where`, `order`, ... statements) anymore with that as I do normally with an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. In the console it generates the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method 'method_call' for #<Array:0x000001063dd658>)
```

**How can I retrieve an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object after I made the above changes?** Or better, there is a way to accomplish what I aim to retrieve with the `@unchecked_articles`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your model looks, but i'd suggest defining a scope for articles.

```
Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :unchecked, where(:checked => false)

  #or this, apologies for somewhat unefficient, but you already seem to have several queries
  scope :unchecked2, lambda { |checked| where(["id not in (?)", checked.map(&:id)]) }

end

Article.unchecked
Article.unchecked2(@unchecked_articles)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `scope`.

```
scope :unchecked, where("checked is FALSE")
```

I've made an assumption there that you flag checked articles like this. After defining a scope you can call `Article.unchecked` to get you AR of unchecked articles.